# SHA1 can't find .jks nad can't update version in android developer console

Tags: android, sha1, developer-console

I found so my old app it's used, but I want publish new version.

But I can't because SHA1 it's wrong, I don't know which .jks is correct I try all from projects but unsuccesfull, please how Can solve my problem thanks.

I use androidstudio. I don't know what you need copy here.

Thanks for help

Comment: if you know all details you have filled while creating keystore file then recreate another keystore file with the same details you have given earlier

Comment: you thing alias, password, name .... ?

Comment: yaa i think it will work

Comment: pfu, I know hos SHA need looks, I can't something replace with thise SHA and work? because I don' tkno how I fill earlier :(